# Matlab function that accepts figure handle or file name as input?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a matlab function that except one input argument, it can be a figure handle or file name to .fig file. If no input is provided I will invoke uigetfile. So far I can not get my function accept figure handle and modify the plot. Remember code should also check if the input is figure-handle or file name.
Please help me with this.

```
 function []=changexlim(varargin)
% This function changes xlim for various values and 
narginchk(0,1)
if nargin==0
    [file,path]=(uigetfile('*.fig','Select matlab figure'));
    fil=fullfile(path,file);
    openfig(fil)
    xlim([0 5])
end

if nargin==1
    check=ishandle(varargin)
    if check==1
        gca=get(varargin,'CurrentAxis')
        xlim(gca,[0 5])
    else if check==0
         openfig(varargin)
         xlim([0 5])    
        end
    end

figure(varargin)
end
```

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`varargin` is a cell array. You have to use the comma-separated list syntax `varargin{:}` to pass it to functions.